# Index Match with Multiple Criteria (and ranged numbers)

Tags: google-sheets, filter, unique, sequence, vlookup

I'm not sure if Index Match is what I'm looking for, but I'm trying to return a certain value when various criteria is met. I'm not sure how to explain this, but the sample sheet is attached to better illustrate what I'm looking for.

Basically, there's a "schedule" sheet, and a "main data" sheet.
I need it so when Col I of "main data" matches Col B of "schedule," and Col G of "main data" falls between the range of Col D and E in "schedule," then it should return the date found in Col C of "main data."

Eg. main data row 2 should return "Nov-10"; whereas row 49 would return "Nov-17"

Having a range here has me at a loss, and I'm not sure how to even approach it. Hopefully this all makes sense.

Thank you in advance!

sample sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KhdsJoD7d5gax5WhHJvXZZoiRRIG_oH6DgXx_snPqzI/edit#gid=1412972392

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use in N2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(I2:I, 
 {UNIQUE(FILTER(schedule!B3:B, schedule!B3:B<>"")), 
  SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(schedule!B3:B), 1, 10000, 10000)}, 2, 0)+G2:G, 
 {VLOOKUP(schedule!B3:B, {UNIQUE(FILTER(schedule!B3:B, schedule!B3:B<>"")), 
  SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(schedule!B3:B), 1, 10000, 10000)}, 2, 0)
 +schedule!D3:D, schedule!C3:C}, 2, 1)))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(G2:G="",,REGEXREPLACE(""&IFNA(VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(I2:I, 
 {UNIQUE(FILTER(schedule!B3:B, schedule!B3:B<>"")), 
  SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(schedule!B3:B), 1, 10000, 10000)}, 2, 0)+G2:G, SORT(
 {VLOOKUP(schedule!B3:B, {UNIQUE(FILTER(schedule!B3:B, schedule!B3:B<>"")), 
  SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(schedule!B3:B), 1, 10000, 10000)}, 2, 0)
 +schedule!D3:D, schedule!C3:C; (
  VLOOKUP(schedule!B3:B, {UNIQUE(FILTER(schedule!B3:B, schedule!B3:B<>"")), 
  SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(schedule!B3:B), 1, 10000, 10000)}, 2, 0)
 +schedule!E3:E+1)*{1, 0}}), 2, 1)), "^0$", )))
```

[image]

Comment: Works great! Thank you so much! Though I noticed that if Entry 7 is still in the list, the date will still show up even though the numbering doesn't fall within the range in the "schedule" table. (It just grabs one of the dates there). If the "Name" doesn't exist, it's blank. Is there a way to stop that from happening?

Comment: @Beee answer updated

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This one is working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Copy this and drag downwards:

#### Formula:

```
=IFERROR(query({filter(schedule!B$3:E, I2 = schedule!B$3:B)}, "select Col2 where Col4 >= "&G2&" and "&G2&" >= Col3"), "")
```

#### Sample:

[image]

Blank is shown on last rows since `G` is not in between `D` and `E` of `schedule`